# Should my game's entities use global variables?

Tags: c++

I have a base class called `Entity` and several sub classes like `Player` and `Goblin`. They all have the method `update(delta)`, but that's not enough to update `Goblin` for example, which also requires `setTargetPosition(vec2)` to get updated properly.

All sub classes are stored together in a single vector `vector<Entity*> entities`.

**Solution 1** is to use some C++ version of JavaScript's `instanceof` and depending on class call methods like `update()` and `setTargetPosition()`.

**Solution 2** is to have a source file with global variables like `Goblin`'s target position and thus only `update()` is necessary because all the data that's needed is in the file with global variables.

What solution is better than those above?

Comment: Who calls `setTargetPosition`? If they know it's a goblin, why would they need to `dynamic_cast` them?

Comment: Is there a reason why `setTargetPosition` can't be called from `update`?

Comment: Because `Goblin` doesn't have the necessary data, in this case the players position which is the target position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your design is at odds with reality, and you need to bring the two into alignment.

The thesis of your design seems to be, essentially, that "everything is an entity" and "everything is in one big list" because you can just `update()` that whole list. That's fine, up until the point where it isn't, which is the point you've reached now.

Your interface for `Entity` is not rich enough to actually express reality: some `Entity` implementations require extra information to fully update themselves, information that is not present in `Entity`. You can address this in a few ways.

One way is to give `Entity` that information; this means storing the target position or target entity in `Entity` itself instead of `Goblin`, which now let's `Entity` have the requisite interface to manage and update the target position. If most subclasses won't use this information, however, this is somewhat wasteful.

What I'd argue is the better way is to simply treat the entities that need special handling (goblins) differently. Store them in a separate `std::vector<Goblin*>` so you *know* everything in that vector is a goblin and can use the goblin-specific APIs. Then you can both `update()` them and set their target positions all in a loop.

This avoids complicating the base class with data and methods that aren't universal to all child types. It also gives you a much stronger locality of reference with respect to the update of the goblin instances: you can know when all the goblins start and stop the update work because there's an explicit loop for it, rather than a loop over the big entity "master list" that is potentially processing entity types in an effectively-random order.

This can be a huge win when when you end up having other logic that really wants to depend on the goblin update being "done," as well as for finding places where your work can be data-parallel and benefit from concurrency.

And of course it doesn't involve `dynamic_cast` or the stashing of information in well-known globals, as requested.

Comment: Did you write an answer about a similar topic not long ago? I tried to find it but I couldn't.

Comment: Probably, this _kind_ of problem is a favorite of mine.

Comment: Thank you Josh for the great answer!

Comment: Good answer. One addition: Even if Goblin is currently the only enemy requiring a target update, it's probably worthwhile to create an interface shared by all (future) entities requiring target updates and use that in the new vector std::vector<INeedsTargetUpdate*>.

Comment: @Josh, if the game has hundreds of entities that all require different method calls before `update()`, is it still good to keep 'em in different vectors? The amount of vectors will become pretty big.

Comment: @Colmud if they require different method calls before update(), why not place those calls in the beginning of update()?

Comment: @Comlud The overhead of the vector is likely trivial compared to the overhead of the entities themselves, so I wouldn’t worry about until profiling tells you it’s an issue. I would say that “hundreds” of entities is _maybe_ an indication that you should rethink when you make a new _type_ of entity versus data on an existing more-general entity. But that’s a different question altogether; you may want to ask about it in the [chat].

Answer (score 5):

Preface: I've designed several game engines in C and C++ by hand and have plenty of experience with game engine architectural patterns and theory

It appears you're designing a game from scratch. Let me first say, **no**, you should *not* use global variables for this purpose. They are stored in what's called the [BSS or Data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#BSS) and while you may not notice the performance hit from cache misses right away, I can guarantee that once you have your game in a more developed state, you will be kicking yourself in the butt for not outlining the design of your custom engine before embarking on the design journey.

In simple terms, a cache miss happens when a program tries to accesses memory which is "far away" from the memory being frequently or currently accessed, which in a game is primarily going to be stack memory. A professor once told me "Cache is king" when it comes to performance.

Aside from that, you may want to read through a common architectural pattern called [Entity-Component-System architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system#targetText=Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system%20(ECS,%2C%20vehicles%2C%20etc.).) which is easy to understand and simple to implement. Since, in a custom engine, you will have a graphics implementation, a serializing implementation for saving loading, potentially a [reflection system](https://preshing.com/20180116/a-primitive-reflection-system-in-cpp-part-1/), audio or the like, your program will be moving through different segments of memory quite often and it is important to begin compartmentalizing your data **now** as it may get quite cluttered quite fast.

Like all tools in the game-dev toolbox, global variables have their time and place. They can be quite useful in reflection with regards to entity-factories when using [static initializers](https://zeux.io/2010/10/10/death-by-static-initialization/), or for [singleton classes](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html). However, for storing the objects which make up the "meat-and-potatoes" of your game, you should certainly plan on a different strategy other than global variables.

For more complete information regarding memory management, [this is an excellent overview of pitfalls and strategies](http://www.allenchou.net/2013/05/memory-management-part-1-of-3-the-allocator/) and may provide a more complete picture to help you plan.